# How to disable all the contents of tab in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created tabwidget and added multiple tabs in it.

[image]

To disable elements in a tag, I can use

```
senEnabled(False)
```

method on each items of tab.

Is there any easy or direct way which can disable all the elements in whole tab in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent widget is disabled then the child widgets will also be disabled, so in your case only the widget page corresponding to the tab will be disabled:

```
page = tab_widget.widget(index_of_tab)
if page is not None:
    page.senEnabled(False)
```

Comment: It means the elements in tabs will be shown but only in setenabled(False) way, am I right?

Comment: @sam I recommend you try since the implementation is simple